# Survivors pursue a myth that there is a machine that can immunize them against radiation

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

Decades ago I read a book that I want to identify. The plot, as I recall it:

- The world had been destroyed by a nuclear war
- There is no place safe from radiation
- Survivors pursue a myth that there is a machine that can immunize them against radiation

edit: Following Möoz advice, after reading "how to ask a good story-id question" I can add:

- The book was part of a collection, very cheap sci-fi books, very common at that time (about 30 years ago). I don't remember the collection name, unfortunately.
- The characters have to wear protective suits and wandered about in anti-radiation vehicles. The world was basically a desert, but there were a very few cities scattered around.
- I believe that one important part in the plot is that the characters find a woman of unknown origin.

Edit: another attempt: does anyone know of other collections, like laser books, edited in the 70s or 80s that maybe had printed the history I´m trying to identify?

Comment: Any more details? Like what do you mean by decades ago? Was it 2 decades or 5? Also, please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if that helps jog your memory, good luck.

Comment: Probably 30 years ago or close to it. I will check this link out for sure, tks.

Comment: That reminds me of a couple of books from 1980 or so called 'Ozymandias' and 'Guardian', by Thomas F. Monteleone.  I don't remember much of the plot except there were people driving around a radioactive wasteland at some point, and there was a godlike AI that I think they were looking for.

Comment: @LAK, I think that's a short story called "Am". But I will research about this author, tks.

Comment: Well, following the lead that @LAK presented, I read the plot of the laser books collection (all 57 of them :) ) and did not find the history I´m after. But it inspired me to edit the post and ask: do anyone know other collections, like laser books, edited in the 70s or 80s that maybe had printed the history I´m trying to identify?